# Automatic import windowbuilder in my own eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, windowbuilder

I have a plugin that depends of windowbuilder plugin.
In eclipse Kepler I only need to install my plugin using a URL.
But in eclipse Mars and Neon I need to install windowbuilder plugin before install my own plugin.
This is the URL to install window builder: http://download.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/WB/release/R201506241200-1/4.5/

This is the error message when I try to install my plugin in eclipse Neon:

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could
>   not be found.   Software being installed: com.myownplugin.feature
>   1.0.0.201608191212 (com.myownplugin.feature.feature.group 1.0.0.201608191212)   Missing requirement: com.myownplugin.editor 1.0.0.201608191212 (com.myownplugin.editor 1.0.0.201608191212) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.wb.core 0.0.0' but it could not be found 
>   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: com.myownplugin.feature 1.0.0.201608191212 (com.myownplugin.feature.feature.group 1.0.0.201608191212)
>       To: com.myownplugin.editor [1.0.0.201608191212]

I tried to create a targe file with windowbuilder in definitions but i dont know why it didnt work.
How can I install only my own plugin without need to install windowbuilder before?

My site.xml is something like that:

```
<site>
   <description name="Update Site" url="http://companyownplugin/stable">
      my plugin
   </description>
   <feature url="features/com.companyownplugin.feature_1.0.0.qualifier.jar" id="com.companyownplugin.feature" version="1.0.0.qualifier">
      <category name="com.companyownplugin.cat"/>
   </feature>
   <category-def name="com.companyownplugin.cat" label="My Plugin"/>
</site>
```

Answer (score 0):

Either add into your update-site a reference to http://download.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/WB/integration/4.6/ , so it will use it to resolve WindowBuilder at installation; or simply include directly the necessary WindowBuilder features into your update-site.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I included my site.xml in question. How can I include the windowbuilder url in this file to resolve at installation? Or this configuration is done in other location?

Comment: I tried to include features in site.xml like: [<feature url="features/org.eclipse.wb.core.java.feature_1.8.0.r45x201506110821.jar" id=....]. And I added the jar in directory features.

But It appers when Im installing the plugin with checkbox and I can dismark the option. I need to force install windowbuild together with my plygin.

Comment: Dependency resolution (with p2) will automatically install dependencies when installing your plugin/feature. If there is a dependency from one of your plugin (via MANIFEST.MF) or feature to parts of WindowBuilder, those will get automatically installed.

Comment: In my MANIFEST.MF I have this Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.wb.core,
 org.eclipse.wb.swing. I tried to put jars in "features" directory but didnt work... Could you please tell me what file to change and an exemple? Thank you a lot.

Comment: At this point, I suggest you to find a tutorial about building update-site and dependency resolution with p2 in Eclipse IDE. Just putting content into folders isn't supposed to work.